# how to visible a link button if empty string is used..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i need to display a link button based on a condition that., if my id value is null i should display my link button..so i used the below condition but not able to display the link button,where i'm using grid view to display the contents

```
 <asp:Panel ID="statusPanel" Visible='<%# (Eval("ID").Equals("")) %>' runat="server">
       <asp:LinkButton ID="UpldBtn" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TransactionID")%>' CommandName="Upload" runat="server">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
 </asp:Panel>
```

and in the same way if my id is null i need to display a tick image but cant able to dipslay it..

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#(Eval("ID").Equals("") ? "" : "images/add_btn.png")%>' />
```

can any one help me where i had made a mistake..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank-You friends..I got the solution.. here is the code..

```
<asp:Panel ID="statusPanel" Visible='<%#Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("ID"))%>' runat="server">
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="UpldBtn" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TransactionID")%>' CommandName="Upload" runat="server">Upload</asp:LinkButton>
                          </asp:Panel>
<%#(Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("ID")) ? "" : "images/add_btn.png")%>
```

Comment: Please mark this as your answer so others can find it.